# How Can I Filter the Results of a Query to an API?

Tags: php, html, api

I am working on a project for a local store making an online search. Right now a search returns a bunch of unnecessary data like when the item was added, consignID, quantity, etc. (You can see the results [here](http://theloftames.com/test/testphp1.php?search=bke)). I'm sure this is simple, but how can I filter the results? Thanks! (Also you can find the API documentation [here](http://wiki.traxia.com/display/guide/List+and+Search+Inventory))

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

$search = $_GET['search'];
if ($search == "") {
    echo "Please enter a query. <a href='/search.php'>Click Here</a> to go back";
  break;
}
else {
$data = array('key' => $API_KEY,
              /*'consignorId' => '1',*/
              'query' => $search,
              'includeItemsWithQuantityZero' => 'false');

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'content' => $data_string
    )
));

$result = file_get_contents('https://user.traxia.com/app/api/inventory', false, $context);


$jsonData = $result;
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$phpArray = $phpArray['results'];
$activeonly = array_filter($phpArray, function($active) { return $status['status']=="ACTIVE"; });
}
?>
<html> 
<table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
     <!-- border, cellspacing, and cellpadding attributes are not recommended; only included for example's conciseness -->
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <?php
           foreach(array_keys($phpArray[0]) as $k) {
              echo "<th>$k</th>";
           }
           ?>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($phpArray as $key => $values) {
           echo '<tr>';
           foreach($values as $v) {
              echo "<td>" . implode('<br /> ', (array)$v) . "</td>";
           }
           echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post your PHP code from testphp1.php so we can help.

Comment: @AndyGee Sorry 'bout that. I added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?
$mykeys = array('consignorId','category','currentPrice');
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
    <!-- border, cellspacing, and cellpadding attributes are not recommended; only included for example's conciseness -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php
        foreach($mykeys as $k) {
            echo "<th>$k</th>";
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($phpArray as $key => $values) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($mykeys as $k) {
                echo "<td>".$values[$k]."</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The documentation doesn't mention a way to limit which API parameters are returned as part of the response object.

On your code's side though, you can simply ignore the fields you don't care about.

I assume you have code similar to this:

```
foreach ($response as $item)
{
    // Create a <tr> with each column being populated by $item[fieldname]
}
```

If you don't want the `consignorId`, don't add `$item['consignorId']` to your output.